# c++ open .txt file and read numbers to place in an array

Tags: c++, file, file-io, fstream

i have a text file that has the numbers on one line like (no spaces between commas):

```
    -1,5,-3,10,500000,-6000
```

so far this is the code i have but i am not getting anything back at all in the vector array

```
fstream fp;
vector<int> numbers;
int number;

fp.open("numbers.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

if(fp.is_open()){
  while(fp >> number){
     numbers.push_back(number);
  }
}

fp.close();

cout << "Numbers:\n";
for (int i=0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
    cout << numbers[i] << '\n';
}
```

i feel like im just not reading the file properly or the whole line is just getting put into the number var. Also, the number of numbers in the file is unknown so i would like to stay away from hardcoding it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fstream fp;
vector<int> numbers;
int number;

fp.open("numbers.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

if(fp.is_open()){
  while(fp >> number){
     numbers.push_back(number);
     fp.get();
  }
}

fp.close();

cout << "Numbers:\n";
for (int i=0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
    cout << numbers[i] << '\n';
}
```

You just forgot about the comma's! use fp.get(); to get rid of them, and then it'll work fine :D

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your input file is not binary - don't use `ios::binary`.

Second of all, you need to split your input tokens. Your input operation will fail every time you stumble upon a comma. You might need to input a character or a string to deal with those.

Answer (score 1):

Your input fails when it trys to insert a `,` into an integer. You should use `getline` to insert the values up until the comma delimiter:

```
while (std::getline(fp, number, ','))
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: doesnt like the getline, i am using namespace std

Comment: @CRS Use `#include <string>`

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
if(fp.is_open()){
  while(fp >> number){
     numbers.push_back(number);
     char dummy_variable_for_the_comma;
     fp >> dummy_variable_for_the_comma; // read and discard a comma
  }
}
```

You have to tell the computer to skip the commas, it won't do that for you.

Comment: @CRS Your code has no check that you successfully open the file. So quite likely that fails and so nothing is read. Do this `if (fp.is_open()) { ... } else { cout << failed to open file\n"; }` and see what happens.

Comment: @CRS BTW just tested your code with my change and it worked for me, so I think the error is that you don't successfully open the file.